# How to get all apps installed on android phone

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-widget, android-layout

This is the code that i have at the moment but i still can't get a list of all the apps on the phone. Does anyone see what i am doing wrong?

```
public class GetAppList extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        try {
            List<PackageInfo> appListInfo1 = this.getPackageManager()
            .getInstalledPackages(0);
            JSONArray ja = new JSONArray();
            try {
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                Object sendDataUrl = null;
                HttpPost request = new HttpPost(sendDataUrl.toString());
                List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                ContextWrapper context = null;
                PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
                List<PackageInfo> appListInfo = pm.getInstalledPackages(0);
                for (PackageInfo p : appListInfo) {
                    if (p.applicationInfo.uid > 10000) {
                        JSONObject jo = new JSONObject();
                        jo.put("label", p.applicationInfo.loadLabel(pm).toString());
                        jo.put("packageName", p.applicationInfo.packageName);
                        ja.put(jo);
                    }
                    System.out.print(ja);
                }        
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
        finally {
            // ... cleanup that will execute whether or not an error occurred ...
        }



}catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO: handle exception
}
finally {
    // ... cleanup that will execute whether or not an error occurred ...
}
    }}
```

Sorry cant get this to format the code properly.

Answer (score 5):

This code logs name and package name of all the installed applications. You can easily check the log using LogCat (if you are using Eclipse).

**Package name** - name of the app's package.

**Name** - text label associated with the application. You can't use just `appInfo.name` as it will return `null`. Using `appInfo.loadLabel(packageManager)` you get the actual app's name like *Speech Recorder* instead of package name *com.android.speechrecorder*.

```
final PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
List<ApplicationInfo> installedApplications = 
   packageManager.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);

for (ApplicationInfo appInfo : installedApplications)
{
    Log.d("OUTPUT", "Package name : " + appInfo.packageName);
    Log.d("OUTPUT", "Name: " + appInfo.loadLabel(packageManager));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is the code I use to list applications:

```
PackageManager pm = this.getPackageManager();
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);

String activityName = rInfo.activityInfo.name;
List<ResolveInfo> list = pm.queryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);

for (ResolveInfo rInfo : list) {
    pkg = rInfo.activityInfo.applicationInfo.packageName;
    if (pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage(pkg) == null) {
      continue;
    }
    String label = rInfo.activityInfo.applicationInfo.loadLabel(pm).toString();
    arrayList.add(new AppEntry(label, activityName, pkg, null));
}
```

If you later on want to run application only knowing pkg and activityName you can do:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intent.setClassName(pkg, activityname);
ctx.startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: This code doesn't cut and paste as correct (errors around String activityName and pkg)...just FYI