# Restrict mobile and wifi data for specific applications

Tags: android, network-traffic

I am trying to create a Data Saver application. So I used this solution [How to get all apps installed on android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5393607/how-to-get-all-apps-installed-on-android-phone), after this, I want to restrict data (Mobile & WiFi) for the selected application. How to do it?

Comment: Please be a bit more specific when asking a question: *What have you tried so far with a code example? ([I downvoted because there is no code](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/))* / *What do you expect?* / *What error do you get?* **For Help take a look at "[How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)"**

Comment: you take some help from this project https://github.com/Romascu/NoRootFirewall-Custom